# To download WindowsPhone8 app form IBM app center, we need AET(app enrolmnt tokens),cost 299$-Symantec cert+99$-Windows dev act,any alternative?

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, code-signing, worklight-appcenter, symantec

Hi we have developed a Windows phone 8 mobile application using IBM worklight. For deploying the application to IBM App Center,application is not downloadable unless signed with Symantec/Microsoft. For this it costs me a lot 299$ + 99 $

> The Windows Phone version of the mobile client is included as an
>   **unsigned Windows Phone application package (.xap)** file in the software
>   delivery. The IBMApplicationCenterUnsigned.xap file is in the
>   ApplicationCenter/installer directory.

**The unsigned .xap file cannot be used directly. You must sign it with your company certificate obtained from Symantec/Microsoft before you can install it on a device.**

> **Optional:** If necessary, you can also build the Windows Phone version
>   from sources. To build the Windows Phone version, you must have the
>   latest version of the Microsoft Visual Studio development tools.

It costs **99$** for windows Developer account and **299$** for

- **Symantec Enterprise mobile code signing certificate**

, with which i can sign the application and upload the Application Enrollment Token(AET-aetx) to IBM application center

Is there any alternative or this is the only way to sign the application.
I explored that Microsoft trusts directly the Symantec but will i be able to sign it using some other certificate by IBM or any other sample certificates for deploying the application to IBM app center.

please suggest

Comment: I dont know whats the OPTIONAL source for windows phone version

Comment: Just side load the app from Visual studio to your win phone 8.

Comment: Can I side load the windows desktop application as we do for mobiles ? Hussam Eddin

Comment: Sorry,I haven't worked on windows desktop actually, Mobile is our target.

Comment: That's great thanks for the reply Hussam Eddin, I should see if some one could respond for this question(Side load windows Desktop Application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM does not provide certificates for you. You need to buy a certificate...

Comment: Hi Idan Adar, can I buy certificate from some other authority or it should be only purchased from Symantec

Comment: From whichever vendor Microsoft supports. Consult the Windows Phone documentation.

Comment: yes it only does with Symantec Idan, i have followed up with documentation. but only for testing purpose this huge amount is ridiculous

Comment: IBM does not control the amount of money Microsoft or Symantec is asking for...

Comment: Idan Adar  have you ever tried of downloading windows phone 8 from application center, it gives error about cannot install the company app... right, so as my question is exactly about that, do you have any idea of signing the worklight build application using SSL or any other low budget certs, I know that Windows only trusts Symantec but for Beta testing kind of thing can i upload any AET or sign using my own SSL or any free certificates if possible

Comment: Information regarding application deployment in Windows Phone can be found here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/r_ac_wp8_enroll_tolens.html%23applicationenrollmenttokensinwindowsphone8?lang=en